# Exceptional C++[Bug]?

Tags: c++

I have been reading `Exceptional C++ by Herb Sutter`. On reaching `Item 32`

I found the following

```
 namespace A 
 {
     struct X;
     struct Y;
     void f( int );
     void g( X );
 }
 namespace B
 {
     void f( int i )
     {
        f( i );   // which f()?
     }
 }
```

> This f() calls itself, with infinite recursion. The reason is that the only visible f() is B::f() itself.
>
> There is another function with signature f(int), namely the one in namespace A. If B had written **"using namespace A;"** or "using A::f;", then A::f(int) would have been visible as a candidate when looking up f(int), and the f(i) call would have been ambiguous between A::f(int) and B::f(int). Since B did not bring A::f(int) into scope, however, only B::f(int) can be considered, so the call unambiguously resolves to B::f(int).

But when I did the following..

```
 namespace A 
 {
     struct X;
     struct Y;
     void f( int );
     void g( X );
 }
 namespace B
 {
     using namespace A;
     void f( int i )
     {
        f( i );   // No error, why?
     }
 }
```

That means Herb Sutter has got it all wrong? If not why dont I get an error?

Comment: Just because something isn't a compile-time error doesn't mean it has well-defined semantics.

Comment: But writing `using A::f` leads to compile time error.

Comment: Depending on your version of the book, it is up to 11 years old.  Any changes in C++03, and soon in C++0x, will not be reflected in its examples.  (I don't know, but I suspect this worked when he first wrote it.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between a using declaration (`using A::f`) and a using directive (`using namespace A`).

A using declaration introduces a name into the scope in which it is used so `using A::f` makes the call to `f` in the definition of `B::f(int)` ambiguous.

A using definition makes members of the namespace visible in the scope in which it is used, but they *appear* as if the name comes from the nearest common scope of the namespace introduced and the namespace in which the using directive was used. This means that `using namespace A;` in this case make the other `f` appear as if it was declared at the global scope but it is still hidden by `B::f(int)`.

(ISO/IEC/BS 14882:2003 7.3.4 [namespace.udir] / 1 for all the standard junkies.)