# typedef resolution across namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef

I am currently confused with the way "using (namespace)" statements work in C++.

I have:

```
//somewhere in included headers
typedef unsigned int uint;

namespace mine {
    typedef unsigned int uint;
}
namespace other {
    using namespace mine;
    void foobar () {
        uint offender = i;
    }
}
```

Results in (paraphrased):
*reference to 'uint' is ambiguous.
candidates are

typedef unsigned int uint

and

typedef unsigned int mine::uint*

Meanwhile, when I do

```
namespace other {
    using namespace mine;
    using mine::uint;

    void foobar () {
        uint offender = i;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine.
It seems strange to me that "using *identifier*;" changes the visibility of other typedef definition (conceals the global one?).
Can someone point me to what kind of rules in C++ govern resolution of typedefs across namespaces?

Comment: Which namespace a declaration made visible due to a using directive (as opposed to a using declaration) appears in is an exact duplicate of the issue in [Exceptional C++\[Bug\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039615/exceptional-cbug)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A name made visible by a *using-directive* appears in the nearest enclosing scope that contains [- directly or indirectly -] both the *using-directive* and the nominated namespace. (7.3.4 [namespace.udir])

This means that both `uint` declarations *appear* at the global namespace scope when looked up after the *using-directive* in `other`.

A *using-declaration*, like any other declaration, declares a name at the scope in which it appears. This is why, in the second example, `using mine::uint;` hides the `uint` introduced by `using namespace mine;` as the latter appears to come from the global scope.

Answer (score 5):

Your original code confuses the compiler, because the uint can be either

```
::uint
```

or

```
::mine::uint
```

therefore compiler throws that error message to you.  In the "fix", the using `mine::uint` explicitly specified that `::mine::uint` shall be preferred.

However, `typedef` conflict shall be avoided IMO.  It makes the code so hard to maintain.

Comment: Is that really the case, i.e. does "using mine::xxx" explicitly specify that whenever xxx occurs in code it will be resolved to mine::xxx.  
Doesn't "using namespace mine" do the same for all identifiers in the namespace mine?

Comment: I think the answers below shall sufficiently answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't cite chapter and verse for you, but this makes sense to me. If the compiler can't find the symbol `uint` in the current namespace, it looks to other namespaces to see if it can find the symbol there. Since it finds it in two other namespaces, it's ambiguous.

When you said `using mine::uint` you imported that symbol into the current block, so it's found before the other namespaces need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't conceal the global one. That's why you have the ambiguity.